# SQL: How can I select table entries within the next three available dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

To clarify the question further...

I have the following Table ORDERS_TAB with some example information:

```
|Order| Launch_Date |
|  1  |   27-Sep-11 |
|  2  |   29-Sep-11 |
|  3  |   30-Sep-11 |
|  4  |   03-Oct-11 |
|  5  |   28-Oct-11 |
|  8  |   10-Oct-11 |
|  7  |   29-Sep-11 |
```

I want to select *all* orders that  have a LAUNCH_DATE value within the next three available days including the current day. So, as today is 29-Sep-11 the three available dates from the table would be 29-Sep-11, 30-Sep-11 and 03-Oct-11. Thus the query would return the result:

```
|Order| Launch_Date |
|  2  |   29-Sep-11 |
|  3  |   30-Sep-11 |
|  4  |   03-Oct-11 |
|  7  |   29-Sep-11 |
```

So I assume I would need to check what the current date is in the system, search for this date or the next available one and then find the next two available dates after that.. the problem is I have no idea how to do this!

All I am looking for is a simple SELECT statement with some conditions but any help is much appreciated,

Thank-you. :)

Comment: How do you determine what an "Available Date" is?

Comment: A date that exists in the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Launch_Date) available_date_index,
    *
  FROM
    ORDERS_TAB
  WHERE
    Launch_Date >= TRUNC(Sysdate)
)
WHERE
  available_date_index <= 3
```

**EDIT** As there is confusion about how DENSE_RANK() works, here is the OP's example...

```
|Order| Launch_Date |    Available_Date_Index
|  1  |   27-Sep-11 | <excluded by WHERE clause>
|  2  |   29-Sep-11 |             1
|  3  |   30-Sep-11 |             2
|  4  |   03-Oct-11 |             3
|  5  |   28-Oct-11 |             5
|  8  |   10-Oct-11 |             4
|  7  |   29-Sep-11 |             1
```

This means that the returned Orders will be `2,3,4,7`.  Exactly as described by the OP.

Comment: @kevin burton : You are incorrect.  `DENSE_RANK()` will sequentially order `29th, 30th, 3rd` as `1,2,3`.  It will return exactly the example given by the OP.

Comment: but what happens if there is no row for the 30th but a row for the 4th...... I put it to you it will return 29th, 3rd, 4th as 1,2,3

Comment: @KevinBurton: Yes, that is what the OP is asking for.  Any data that exists for the next three distinct dates, starting from today.  Therefor, DESNSE_RANK() will index `29th, 3rd, 4th` as `1,2,3`, which is exactly what the OP is asking for...

Comment: My developer does not seem to like this query it's throwing a wobbly

Comment: Sorry if I could have been clearer... I want to return the next date in time.. So if I had data for 29th Sep, 5th Oct, 9th Oct, 23rd Oct for today, I want to return the data for 29 Sep, 05 Oct and 9th Oct.

Comment: @TamaraJQ : An `OP` is an `Original Post`; basically, your question.  Or sometimes refers directly to you as the person who asked the question.  What is the exact error you get from this query?  I don't recognise `wobbly` as an error message :)

Comment: @Dems, Lol. I am new to these slang words! OP could mean old person for all I know! It is an ORA-00936 missing expression error. It looks like your code will work I will try it again now.

Comment: Depending on data, may need to truncate launch date to get three dates, versus three different times on the same date, since Oracle stores time in "DATE" columns and by default doesn't display time, that can get missed. Like so `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY trunc(Launch_Date)) `

Comment: @ShannonSeverance : Agreed, if the dates *can* include a timepart, that is the exact syntax required.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dems. Great answer, works really well. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from ORDERS_TAB where Launch_Date in
   (select Launch_Date from
          (select distinct Launch_Date from ORDERS_TAB
                  where Launch_Date >= '2011-09-29' order by Launch_Date)
    WHERE rownum <= 3)
```

Comment: Doh, yes, this is what the OP wanted

Comment: Way too complicated... IMHO it's simpler than this

Comment: @m0skit0, but your answer will not return the correct answer if there are "holes" in the dates in `Launch_Date`.

Comment: @m0skit0 : The OP wants the next three dates that exist in the data.  Looking at the example the dates are NOT sequential, they skip from 30-Sep to 03-Oct.  This answer would include the 03-Oct value, yours would not.

Comment: @Dems what is an OP? Dems is right. There are gaps in the data hence why I want to select the next date which is available in the table.

Comment: Doesn't matter, DB server takes account of that (Oracle 11 here)

Comment: Ah yes, I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: @TamaraJQ : Delete the `TOP 3` part, and try a where clause of `WHERE rownum <= 3` instead.

Comment: @KevinBurton : This will return 4 rows, not 3.  And that is actually what the op is asking for.  Identify the next three dates that actually exist in the data, and then return all the data (however many rows that may be) for those three dates.

Comment: Agreed - I think my version is simpler though

Comment: Yes, @HughJones, but your code will not work when there are duplicate `Launch_Date`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from order_tab where launch_date in
(    
  select launchdate
    from
    (
      select launchdate from order_tab
      where launch_date >= SysDate -- Check this
      order by launch_date
    )  where rownum <= 3
)
```

How does that look ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As the comments point out, the following doesn't work
maybe go for

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS_TAB WHERE LaunchDate IN (
  SELECT TOP(3) LaunchDate FROM ORDERS_TAB ((possibly WHERE LaunchDate > GETDATE()?))
  ORDER BY LaunchDate DESC )
```

Comment: Oops. I could edit and fix, but it would be identical to the Albin Sunnanbo answer, and it's probably better to leave this here as an example on how not to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS_TAB WHERE sysdate - launch_date <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This doesn't seem to work though, it selects dates from 27-Sep onwards.

Comment: It selected dates from 26/09 on my DB though... Make sure what's the timer is set in the DB server.

Comment: It needs `>= 1` as well as `<= 3` to work as designed.  But even then it will not account for the example given in the question (with returned dates of 29th, 30th and 3rd)

Comment: Seems to work correctly on my DB. If I try with <= 30, it returns dates from october 31st as well.

Comment: @m0skit0: You're not paying attention then.  The OP wants `The next 3 distinct dates that exist in the data`.  If those dates are `1st, 2nd , 5th` your example will only give `1st, 2nd` and NOT include `5th`.  `DENSE_RANK()` and/or `SELECT TOP 3 DISTINCT` ensure that the `5th` is included.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't pay attention. @Kevin: nonsense or explain yourself better.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM ORDERS_TAB  where Launch_Date between '29-sep-11' and   ADDDATE('2007-09-01', 3);
try this, hope this help you.

Comment: Again, this does NOT account for the gap between `30-Sep` and `03-Oct`.